# How do I add a new column on sql

Tags: sql, dataset

This isn't exactly a table I think, but I just need to add a new column that gives me the average number of people with a businesses [image]

Comment: Hi jorge, to get a better response, may I suggest the following changes:
1) add a tag for which language you are using (perhaps python?)
2) paste the code from the jupyter cell directly into the question and format it as code (not in the image)
3) specify exactly what you want the outlook to look like. Are you just wanting average added to the current structure, or will the structure change? Be specific. 
4) specify the calculation for the average and expected values for an example

Comment: p.s. If this is python, you may find all of this easier if you read the data into a dataframe and add the column with pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to display a new colum in your result
or add automaticaly this average in your database ? (edit not possible for a join table

For the first response you can try this :

```
SELECT *, (B.total_buisinesses / P.total_people) / 100 AS PERCENTAGE
FROM ...
```

(Edit : Only if you merge your table)

For the second, you can create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE your_table SET percentage = (total_buisinesses / total_people) * 100
    WHERE SA2_Code = NEW.SA2_Code;
END;
```

NOTE: Depending on what database you are using, you may have to do a single UPDATE statement to populate the the PERCENTAGE column for existing rows (the trigger may only take care of new inserts).

Also add code to the trigger which prevents divide by zero errors.